# Closet bolts for cast iron toilet flange

Tags: plumbing

I have a toilet issue. I noticed my toilet was rocking from side to side. I pulled on the brass closet bolt and it was loose, so much so that it came up in my hand. I removed the toilet and the bolt had sheared off. The flange itself seems secure and in reasonably good shape, although it sits to far below the finished floor. I would like to use the flange and use extensions but need a way to make sure the flange and/or toilet stays put
Does anyone know how cast iron flanges are attached to a concrete slab?  Would I be able to remove what is left of the bolt with an easy out and then put in another?
Thanks

Comment: Answers go down there, @Armand ;)

Answer (score 2):

The limited number of closet bolts I've seen are replaceable by sliding the bolt sideways so its head moves into an opening in the flange big enough for the bolt head, then just lift it out. Install a new bolt by doing the reverse.

Comment: And now delete your comment as answer, please.